# Python regex - difference between search and find all

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use python regex on a URL string.

```
id= 'edu.vt.lib.scholar:http/ejournals/VALib/v48_n4/newsome.html'
>>> re.search('news|ejournals|theses',id).group()
'ejournals'
>>> re.findall('news|ejournals|theses',id)
['ejournals', 'news']
```

Based on the docs at http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs, it says search() matches the first one and find all matches all the possible ones in the string.

I am wondering why 'news' is not captured with search even though it is declared first in the pattern.

Did i use the wrong pattern ? I want to search if any of those keywords occur in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking about it backwards. The regex goes through the target string looking for `"news"` OR `"ejournals"` OR `"theses"` and returns the first one it finds. In this case `"ejournals"` appears first in the target string.

Answer (score 3):

The `re.search()` function stops after the first occurrence that satisfies your condition, not the first option in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there are some other differences between ***search*** and ***findall*** which aren't stated here.
For example:

[python-regex why findall find nothing, but search works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772736/python-regex-why-findall-find-nothing-but-search-works)

Comment: Please consider moving the content of the question into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`id= 'edu.vt.lib.scholar:http/ejournals/VALib/v48_n4/newsome.html'

> > > re.search('news|ejournals|theses',id).group()
> > >       'ejournals'

## re.search -> search for first appearance in string and then exit.

> > > re.findall('news|ejournals|theses',id)
> > >       ['ejournals', 'news']

## re.findall -> search for all occurrences of match in string and return in list form.