# python - regex why does `findall` find nothing, but `search` works?

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$')
>>> str = '42'
>>> reg.search(str).group()
'42'
>>> reg.findall(str)
['']
>>>
```

python regex
Why does `reg.findall` find nothing, but `reg.search` works in this piece of code above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have capture groups (wrapped with parenthesis) in the *regex*, `findall` will return the match of the captured group; And in your case the captured group matches an empty string; You can make it non capture with `?:` if you want to return the whole match; `re.search` ignores capture groups on the other hand. These are reflected in the documentation:

*re.findall:*

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups;** this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group.

*re.search:*

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string.

```
import re
reg = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$')
s = '42'
reg.search(s).group()
​# '42'

reg.findall(s)
# ['42']
```

Comment: Thank you !!! `code`>>> phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d)-\d\d\d\d')
>>> phoneNumRegex.findall('Cell: 415-555-9999 Work: 212-555-0000')
[('415', '555'), ('212', '555')]
>>> phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(?:\d\d\d)-(?:\d\d\d)-\d\d\d\d')
>>> phoneNumRegex.findall('Cell: 415-555-9999 Work: 212-555-0000')
['415-555-9999', '212-555-0000']
>>> phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d)-(?:\d\d\d)-\d\d\d\d')
>>> phoneNumRegex.findall('Cell: 415-555-9999 Work: 212-555-0000')
['415', '212'] `code`