# Date extract regex works online testing facilities but not with python regex library

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract date from a sentence.

These are the valid date types

```
dd.mm.yy
dd.mm.yyyy
d.m.yy
d.m.yy
dd-mm-yy
dd-mm-yyyy
dd/mm/yy
dd/mm/yyyy
```

The following regex does the job well.

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

I tested it on multiple online regex testers such as https://www.regexpal.com/

Then I tried it in python with the following code, which could not extract the date portion.

```
def validate_date(text):
    date_regex = '^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'
    return re.findall(date_regex, text)


date = validate_date("02.02.2020")
print(date)
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Please add example text to the question.

Comment: Include a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Comment: Why is the regex so complicated ? Please explain the case you want to handle . You'd better split in 3 different regex as I see 3 `|` OR

Comment: @azro add the valid cases

Comment: I'd say it would be more easy to try/except the parsing into a date with the different format, it all fails, it fail, less performant but much more readable

Comment: my question is the reason for not working in python but online. not the complexity or performance. sorry

Comment: @azro - the regex is so complicated because it handles things like month lengths (so it won't match "31.4.2020") and checking that the separators match (so it won't match "30-4.2020"). I don't think it checks leap years, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two Issues**

1. Need to use raw rawstring r'...' in regex pattern
2. re.search works not re.findall in this case [see answer to why does `findall` find nothing, but `search` works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772736/python-regex-why-does-findall-find-nothing-but-search-works).  So can use search to find first occurrence of date in string

**Code**

```
def validate_date(text):
    date_regex = r'^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'

    return re.search(date_regex, text)
```

**Test**

```
date = validate_date("02.02.2020")
print(date.group())
# Output: 02.02.2020
```

Comment: I write this comment for two reasons, first of all thank you for the correct answer. Also, thank you very much for answer to the exact point of the question, not other unrelated issues. You might see the comments and other answers. I downvoted some answers which results  a downvote against the question and answer deletions. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @DarryIG Your output is not correct. # Output: 02.02.2020 You will get search Obejct as `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='02.02.2020'>` You need to add `.group()`

Answer (score 1):

Please append prefix `r` before regex expression.

i.e.

```
date_regex = r'^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'
```

Here,  the r prefix on the string literal is superfluous. However, it is conventionally used for regular expression literals. r'' (and other r prefixed Python quoting forms) are for defining "raw" strings ... which is to say that they are strings for which there is (almost) no evaluation of the string (for \ character sequences).

Solution:

```
import re
def validate_date(text):
    date_regex = r'^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'
    return re.finditer(date_regex, text)


date = validate_date("02.02.2020")
for match in date:
    print(match.group())
    # match start: match.start()
    # match end (exclusive): match.end()
    # matched text: match.group()
```

Comment: this returns give me [('', '', '', '.')] not the date

Comment: That's right; `findall` returns the list of tuples of capturing groups, not the full matches. If you test on regex101.com you'll see the groups that are matched are in fact the separators. You can either (a) put a capturing group for the whole date, or (b) use one of the other functions (eg. `finditer`) to get the whole matches rather than the captured groups.

Comment: @sabik Thanks I have added `finditer` with some code changes.

Answer (score 0):

When writing regexes, use the `r'...'` form of strings:

```
    date_regex = r'^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$'
```

That makes sure that backslashes (`\`) are interpreted as part of the regex (rather than in the way they're treated in other strings).

Comment: give me [('', '', '', '.')] not the date

Comment: That's right; `findall` returns the list of tuples of capturing groups, not the full matches. If you test on regex101.com you'll see the groups that are matched are in fact the separators. You can either (a) put a capturing group for the whole date, or (b) use one of the other functions (eg. `finditer`) to get the whole matches rather than the captured groups.